# Maximal screen resolution for external monitor breaks desktop

Tags: unity, 11.04, resolution, monitor

Whenever I'm plugging in my external monitor into my notebook and changing the screen resolution to the maximum state, the desktop will get broken in a way:

- A third of the whole desktop space is not visible at all.

I can see the whole panel as well as the Unity side bar to the left, but the desktop space with all the windows in it is not completely visible. It's blanked out.
In case of opening the Unity menu bar, I can type something in it. As soon as close the menu bar, the upper part stays visible and hangs:

[image]

Any ideas about that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Weird, that looks like an issue with Unity.. You can rule it out being a Unity problem, do you mind logging in to Gnome?

If gnome works fine, then I suggest you go file a bug in the Ubuntu Launchpad system - after running full system updates and verifying this isn't already a solved issue of course.

If it's not actually a window manager thing, then I suppose it could be Xorg. Maybe you can fiddle around with the "Monitors" gui - try changing things around, just for the sake of getting it to switch modes/configs around, it may stumble on the correct layout. Or better yet, if you have a third party video driver config tool, you can use that to try different settings.

A final thing you could try is booting off the LiveCD - if you can reproduce this behavior in there, then that implies (to me) that the issue isn't a user-induced configuration one, but rather elsewhere.

Good luck!